# Android layout with LinearLayout and orientation vertical not working

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, android-linearlayout

I have a two fragments and they are hosted on activity that has following layout

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:padding="20dp"
>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/frameContainer1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"


    ></LinearLayout>
 <LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:id="@+id/frameContainer"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   ></LinearLayout>


 </LinearLayout>
 </FrameLayout>
```

and  `frameContainer1` is like this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/frameContainer"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/image1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

and other container is like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/image1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/name1"/>
     </RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is the appearance is completely out. The `frameContainer1` is appearing on top on action bar. what I want is frameContainer1 appear before the other container vertically.

How can I fix it?

**Update** Small image in the screenshot is frameContainer1 content

[image]

Comment: Could you add screenshot?

Comment: Where is the relationship between ``LinearLayout : frameContainer1`` and ``image1`` ??? Can you show full xml file

Comment: @DanhDC one user formatted my question. is it making more sense?

Comment: @Alex Can you show your screenshot when run this layout, it will easy to understand your problem

Comment: try using relative layout or linear layout as root layout. I mean to say remove frame layout and keep only linear layout which is 2nd layer.

Comment: please attach screenshot or something that help to understand your question so it can be work out @Alex

Comment: @AmitVaghela I have added screenshot

Comment: do you want to show image in actionbar ? @Alex

Comment: @AmitVaghela no I dont it just appearing there

Answer (score 0):

**Hope this helps.**

Please remove your `FrameLayout` from your .xml file

Remove this,

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"    
android:padding="20dp">

</FrameLayout>
```

because it is parent of other layout.

Other thing is you are including `Framelayout inside Linearlayout` so it will not take effect properly.

Comment: remove framelayout. OK. but replace it with what?

Comment: Linearlayout should be parent. @Alex